# Way to get a pid of process that calls system call?

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension

I made a kext to use my system call instead of an existing system call on reference to 
[Re-routing System Calls](https://github.com/dwalters/pt_deny_attach).

During a test, I wonder which process calls this systemcall.

I need to allow applications to continue normally except the specified process.

Is there anything that obtain the information of calling process?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the source for the [regular implementation of the `ptrace` system call](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.9.2/bsd/kern/mach_process.c) you can see that it works with the `struct proc` representing the calling process that's passed in as the first argument:

```
int
ptrace(struct proc *p, struct ptrace_args *uap, int32_t *retval)
{
    // …   
    if (uap->req == PT_DENY_ATTACH) {
        proc_lock(p);
        if (ISSET(p->p_lflag, P_LTRACED)) {
            proc_unlock(p);
            KERNEL_DEBUG_CONSTANT(BSDDBG_CODE(DBG_BSD_PROC, BSD_PROC_FRCEXIT) | DBG_FUNC_NONE,
                          p->p_pid, W_EXITCODE(ENOTSUP, 0), 4, 0, 0);
            exit1(p, W_EXITCODE(ENOTSUP, 0), retval);
            /* drop funnel before we return */
            thread_exception_return();
            /* NOTREACHED */
        }
        SET(p->p_lflag, P_LNOATTACH);
        proc_unlock(p);

        return(0);
    }
```

You can use the functions in `<sys/proc.h>` to get information on the given process, such as `proc_pid` to find the pid.

Comment: You could probably just call [`proc_selfpid()`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=xnu-2050.18.24;im=bigexcerpts;i=proc_selfpid) in this case.

Comment: In practice you're right. In theory a caller could presumably pass a different process via the argument if the function were called directly rather than as a result of a system call from a user process.